# PHP.ini Default Dir Extensions

Tags: php, apache

I have my php.ini as follows:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext"
```

I will distribuite my php application but I was wondering that not all users have their Windows OS on the default C:\, suppose they use another letter like Y:.

How could I change "automatically" to the correct path. Like:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "Y:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext"
```

I can't go to every computer and change the default settings. So is there a way to do this by not changing it directly?

Comment: that'd be something your installer has to take care of.

Comment: Does your application require that PHP and Apache already be installed? Look at the default ini files shipped with PHP and you will see that they simply have ext for the directory not a full path.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. How can I modify this file during the installation process?

Comment: Dave, I will add the Apache and PHP folder with my own configuration. So instead of: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext I'll put \ext ?

Answer (score 27):

This seems to use `ext` relative to the PHP directory itself:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

I.e. it should be irrelevant what drive or path PHP is installed on, as long as the extensions are in the ext directory.

Comment: Relative paths don't always seem to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489141/3177115