# php spark serve Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\CLI\mb_strpos()

Tags: php, localhost, codeigniter-4, mbstring

I'm new to PHP and trying to open the CodeIgniter 4 welcome page by using localhost (I don't have any server programs like XAMPP since it's a company computer and PHP works fine with its built-in server.)

When I try to run the command: `php spark serve` on the terminal, it gives an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\CLI\mb_strpos() in C:\Users\50290536\Desktop\php-test\system\CLI\CLI.php:776
```

I enabled the necessary extensions in the `php.ini` file and the file: `php_mbstring.dll` is available in the directory `php/ext`.

I also tried to run the command: `php spark` to see if `spark` works fine but in that case, I got the following error:

```
The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: curl, intl, mbstring at SYSTEMPATH\Codeigniter.php:224
```

All these extensions are enabled in the `php.ini` file and their respective `.dll` files are available in the directory `php/ext`.

##### Details:

---

*PHP version:* `v8.2`

*CodeIgniter 4 framework version:* `v4.2.10`

*Currently enabled PHP modules after running the command: `php -m`*

```
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
Phar
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib
```

Comment: Please, open your terminal/command prompt, run this command, `php -m` , then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74813216/edit), and share the output. This command will list all currently enabled modules.

Comment: In addition, navigate to the file at the path: `your-project-root-directory-here/system/CodeIgniter.php`. In that file share the class property value corresponding to: `public const CI_VERSION = '...'` This will indicate the current framework version.

Comment: Thank you, I added CI version and enabled modules.

Comment: As shown in the output of currently enabled modules, the modules that CodeIgniter 4 depends on namely: `curl`, `intl`, `mbstring` appear to be **missing**. The closest *culprit* is that you're likely editing the wrong `php.ini` configuration file.

Comment: What is your current operating system? If you're using *'Windows'*, ensure that you've enabled/uncommented the [directory path in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b9cd1cdb4f236b7e336b688b16d58a913f4d5c69/php.ini-production#L774)

Comment: I also hope that you're editing a configuration file labeled: `php.ini` and *not* `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production`

Comment: Well actually there wasn't a php.ini file and someone suggested to copy the php.ini-development file and rename it as php.ini then make the changes. So I did as he said. Did I make a mistake? and yes my operating system is windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the **extension_dir** directive in *php.ini* was relative path. If you change it to absolute it should works. For example:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
```

Alternatively, you can try with these values: "./ext" or ".\ext" or "ext".
Make sure you uncomment the directive. (Just delete the semicolon from the beginning)

It is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74866) on some machine/version.

As you said your OS is Windows, you may check if it resolves the problem. I think if the `php -m` command lists the *mbstring* extension, then it will fix your original problem, and the CodeIgniter spark will works fine.

Make sure you edit the right php configuration file. You can find the location of your php with the `which php` or `where php` commands.

*And yes, you can just simply move the php.ini-development to php.ini, it should work.*

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489141/7742526 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74866